# Why is the effect of beta-branching neglected in this comparison of SN2 reaction rates?

Tags: organic-chemistry, halides, hydrocarbons, nucleophilic-substitution

> Which compound would give a faster S<sub>N</sub>2 reaction?
>
> 1. 2-bromobutane
> 2. 1-bromo-2-methylpropane

The answer is given (2).

While I agree that the primary position is preferred as compared to the secondary position (for an S<sub>N</sub>2 attack), but won't beta branching hinder the nucleophile's attack, hence, reducing the reactivity for S<sub>N</sub>2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the beta branching will hinder the nucleophile a bit, but the substrate is still a primary halide with 2 hydrogens on the carbon that is attacked. The steric effect of having a methyl group and a hydrogen on that carbon vs two hydrogens is very much larger.